# Add a new column using apply and lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new column to a datafram and complete de values of that column indicating with a 1 if it is larger than a given number or 0 if it is smaller.

I`ve tried this:

```
median = df['% Renewable'].median()
df['HighRenew'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x < median else 1, axis=1)
```

It gives me an error. 
Is it correct to use apply + lambda??

Comment: Yes it is, but you should've used a particular column, not the whole `df`…

Comment: _It gives me an error._ Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Also, why are you seemingly using 0 and 1 instead of actual boolean values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use  `apply` against a column, ex:

```
df['HighRenew'] = df['% Renewable'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < median else 1, axis=1)
```